# Visual Studio 2012 & Classic ASP indentation (Smart)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, asp-classic, vbscript, indentation

First of all, this is a known issue in 2012 (Worked fine in VS 2008) (Although it’s certainly not widely reported with classic ASP being so old):

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/766046/indentation-in-visual-studio-2012

MS have closed this as "Not Reproducible" which is bull!

Just to explain the issue, take the following example:

[image]

Say my cursor is on line 60 after the `")` pressing Enter there is placing my cursor at `'A` - it should be placing it at `'B`!

Now then, I can force VS to place the cursor at `'B` by changing indenting from "Smart" to "Block":

[image]

Unfortunately; "Block" is just as infuriating, i.e. pressing Enter after writing `If X = Y then` puts the cursor at the same indentation level as the `If` instead of `If` + 1

My question: has anyone managed to get "Smart" indenting working in classic asp files, if so - how?

**Edit:** here is a little video demonstrating the problem (I type "???" every time the cursor has moved to the wrong location)

http://www.heavencore.co.uk/filehub/Videos/Tech/VisualStudio2013_ClassicASP.mp4

Comment: Facing the same issue, did you find any solution yet?

Comment: @YvesR I've not found a solution yet i'm afraid :'(

Comment: Facing fame issue, never found any solution...

Answer (score 0):

Try the hot keys for auto-formatting of code in VS2012.

to format section: ctrl + e, ctrl + f

to format document ctrl + e, ctrl + d

also. Consider a better VBscript editor, like [VBSEdit](http://www.vbsedit.com/) which has the "Reformat Code" option in the "Edit.." drop down and will auto-block your code.

Comment: format document is `ctrl+k > ctrl+d`. format selection is `ctrl+k > ctrl+f`. Nice VBScript editor linked though.